# Use htaccess to add subdirectory to url while displaying base url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I have searched so many variations of this but can't seem to find exactly what I need. I need to add a directory to a URL but display the content of the base URL.

e.g. **mydomain.com/directory** to display content at **mydomain.com** while display (*not* changing) **mydomain.com/directory** in the address bar.

In case it's important, it's a Wordpress install, and it can't be moved to this directory manually; this would be the simplest option I know.

I have changed to permalinks to include the added directory so this only needs to affect the base/home page; I thought this may make this easier but can remove if a solution works across the whole site. So, if an additional rule could be included so it only works on base URL, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the current set of rewriting rules into the question (there is an "edit" button below it). So those rules created by wordpress itself and any other rules you currently have in place.

Comment: Also it makes sense that you include your best effort in implementing the required rule. Along with a description what works and what does _not_ work as desired. As precise as possible. Otherwise we will all only repeat what you already tried.